# Script to test staging server statuses

Tags: bash

I am just trying to write a script to test the staging server statuses for my organization. What i am looking is to add a loop in the script, that checks all the server status and alerts us by an email or a message something like that when a server broken down or low! how can I do it

This is how we want the script to look like, I am not sure how to write it

```
#!/bin/bash
array[server1, server2..]
 loop()
   if (condition to check all the servers)
   then
     echo "server is in good status"
   else
     echo "server is down" -->if its down an email to 
                                    Example@example.com
   fi
```

This is what I tried, any suggestion and help please will be great!

```
#!/bin/bash

    ping -c $1
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
          echo "server is alive"
    else
         echo "this was't was good server"
    fi
```

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: a semicolon ; is missing just before **then**, see http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-6.html

Comment: @TomKuschel: No. A question is missing.

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: I mean  this was just a rough copy paste, I am able execute the above script by correcting it by above mentioned comments(Thanks a lot for that@cyrus, @Tom Kuschel, Appreciated!). But I think I am looking for better script i guess.

Comment: How do you call this script, and what's the problem?

Comment: Also i want to add a loop in the script which will check all our servers and send a email or a message for us if any of the server is broken!

Comment: I recommend installing a monitoring software.

Comment: Like? any examples please?

Comment: One observation. Instead of `ping ...; if [ $? = 0 ]; ...`, just do `if ping ...; then ...`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want something like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

ping_check() {
    ping -c 1 $server &>/dev/null
}

servers=(server1 server2)

for server in ${servers[@]}; do
    if ping_check; then
        printf "%s\n" "Check Successful"
    else
        printf "%s\n" "Check failed"
    fi
done
```